# how to put \n value or <br> in (new line) in BasicNameValuePair

Tags: android, http, android-webview

I want to send message with many new line or some bold text or also with some hyperlink

For example: Below is my code

```
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
  String model = Build.MODEL + ",  " + Build.MANUFACTURER;
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "Your Last Alert:  On "+mDate+" at "+mTime+", "+ model +" reported that its battery level was down to "+batteryLevel+". You might want to get it on a charger before it's too late! &nbsp;&nbsp Do you know where "+model+" is? </br></br> Click "+s+" to view in Google Maps.\n To find "+model+" with the Last Alert app on Android-phone, click here. \n\n\n\n\n\n Last Known Location : \n San Francisco California United States 94108"+"\n\n\n\n\n GPS Coordinates \n"+lat+", "+lon+"Altitude\n"+alt+"\n\nLocation Accuracy"+"16.40ft Diameter"));
```

I have used `&nbsp;` for space, `<br>` for new line also `\n` for new line but the problem is message in sent in only plain text only ( i have sent mail in gmail which is my account)
like below

```
 Your Last Alert: On 10/04/2012 at 03:23 pm, LG-P500, LGE reported that its battery level was down to 100. You might want to get it on a charger before it's too late!  &nbsp Do you know where LG-P500, LGE is? Click https://maps.google.com/maps?q=0.0,0.0 to view in Google Maps. To find LG-P500, LGE with the Last Alert app on Android-phone, click here. Last Known Location : San Francisco California United States 94108 GPS Coordinates 0.0, 0.0Altitude -1.79769313486231E308 Location Accuracy16.40ft Diameter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess.. Try replacing "`</br></br>`" with "`<br/><br/>`". This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you set the "content-type" (in the header of your http request) at:
   `text/html` ?
2. Wrap your message into `<html>`
3. Use `<br/>` tag instead of `\n`